# Sweep funds from all accounts into one account

Tags: web3js

How can i sweep funds of all ethereum accounts into one eth wallet using web3 in ubuntu server?

Is there any example for the same? i found an example but that is not working for me.

Comment: what do you mean by all accounts?

Comment: i have lots of accounts on my server in ethereum node. So all users deposit ETH into our website and all those deposit should be moved to my wallet

Answer (score 0):

Use the accounts one by one and create transactions. There's no automated method to do that.

To withdraw all funds from your account you need to account for the gas cost. If you only need to send funds to another account the transaction will use `21000 gas` this means that your gas cost will be `gasPrice * 21000`.

If for example you have `1 ETH` in your account, and the gas cost is `20 GWei`, you will use `42000 GWei` to pay for the transaction. Doing the difference you are left with

```
1 ETH - 20 GWei * 21000 = 0.99958 ETH
```

It's easier if you make all the calculations in Wei. Use this website to better understand Ethereum units
https://etherconverter.online/

Comment: Shall i set a cron job per minute to go one by one? Or a loop should be used?

Comment: It depends on your usecase. You can activate it in a lot of ways: cronjob, on each new block. It depends how often you need to do it. Are you trying to steal funds?

Comment: Do you know why i get Undefined with this line? `web3.eth.gasPrice`. I'm not that much lucky to get a chance to steal lol

Comment: Did you connect first? Where did you connect to? Do other methods work (like `web3.eth.blockNumber`)?
If you don't figure it out quickly create a new question and add as much info as you can

Comment: I'm actually able to make payment from my wallets, But Im not sure how to calculate GAS price to sweep account balance to 0. If i get to know how to calculate GAS correctly then my problem will be resolved

Comment: I've modified my answer to help you calculate tx cost, thus find out how much exactly you can transfer (considering tx fees)